# How do i emulate a virtual MSP430 microcontroller without connecting the physical board to my pc in ti CCS?

Tags: c, embedded, texas-instruments, code-composer

I am trying to run codes in my ccs on microcontroller and other electronic components but i do not actually have the board and i am thinking there is a way it can be simulated. After building and running my project, i get the error that USB FET is not initialized and i understand that because i haven't actually connected a microcontroller via USB because i don't have one and i am trying to simulate one anyway. How do i go about it in Code composer studio, specifically version 7?

I have searched online about how it can be simulated, like a virtual microcontroller sort of but all the solutions i get talks about having the actual board.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, and read "[ask]". -- Did you ask the manufacturer of the IDE and the board? What did you receive? Did you visit their forum and searched for relevant posts?

Comment: You mean _simulate_ rather than _emulate_.  If your toolchain includes a simulator, it should be pretty obvious (probably where you define the debug connection).